# How to return Associative Array from API in Magento 2

Tags: api, magento2, soap, rest-api, service-contract

I have created Custom Api which returns `associativeArray`.

1. If I use `associativeArray` it's giving error
2. If I use `string[]` it's working

   But I want to return `associativeArray`.

> Error: Class "array" does not exist. Please note that namespace must
>   be specified

**Example Methods:**

```
 /**
     * Create multi Customers
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer);
```

`save` method working fine.

```
 /**
     * Create multi Customers
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
     * @return array()|associativeArray()
     */
    public function save1(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer);
```

`save1` method returning error.

> Error: Class "array()" does not exist. Please note that namespace must
>   be specified

So how can I return `associativeArray`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319266/93504

Answer (score 15):

Custom data interface should be created to represent key-value pairs, e.g.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;

/**
 * Interface which represents associative array item.
 */
interface AssociativeArrayItemInterface
{
    /**
     * Get key
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey();

    /**
     * Get value
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue();
}
```

Then for the new service method it is possible to specify:
 
`@return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\AssociativeArrayItemInterface[]`.

Service layer must comply with some rules to be exposed via SOAP and REST. It is impossible to represent associative arrays in WSDL without key-value data interfaces, all complex entities in WSDL must be described using primitive types (but this will make it more difficult for clients written in strictly typed languages to consume such API).

There is one exception supported though, but is highly discouraged and should be used only in very special cases. If return or param type will be specified as `mixed`, it will be transformed in WSDL into `anyType`.

Comment: @magentotwo did it work for you?

Comment: I have some other, So didn't tried. I will back soon.. Thanks for your response

Comment: Thank you Alex, Your answer give me a idea to solve my question :)  you can check the same here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247801/how-can-we-return-an-array-of-search-results-in-apis-magento-2
+1 for your answer.

Comment: Nice answered it's useful for API

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick:

```
/**
* @return \stdClass[] options
*/
public function getOptions();
```